# Woocommerce: Changing the "# in stock" text

Tags: wordpress, tags, woocommerce, stock

I need to change the "**# in stock**" text to "**# deals left**".

I added the following code to the function.php file but this removes the actual number.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'custom_get_availability', 1, 2);

function custom_get_availability( $availability, $_product ) {
//change text "In Stock' to 'SPECIAL ORDER'
if ( $_product->is_in_stock() ) $availability['availability'] = __('SPOTS LEFT', 'woocommerce');

//change text "Out of Stock' to 'SOLD OUT'
if ( !$_product->is_in_stock() ) $availability['availability'] = __('SOLD OUT', 'woocommerce');
    return $availability;
}
```

Can anybody help with this?

Answer (score 13):

you can try below code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'custom_get_availability', 1, 2);

function custom_get_availability( $availability, $_product ) {
  global $product;
  $stock = $product->get_total_stock();

  if ( $_product->is_in_stock() ) $availability['availability'] = __($stock . ' SPOTS LEFT', 'woocommerce');
  if ( !$_product->is_in_stock() ) $availability['availability'] = __('SOLD OUT', 'woocommerce');

  return $availability;
}
```

Comment: This 'kind of' works for me, but its inputting the incorrect stock number. my product is set to have 14 available, but on the front end it's showing 70. This makes no sense!

Comment: If this is on a child theme, should this be added to the functions.php of the child theme?

Comment: this broke my theme!

Answer (score 2):

This works better in WC > 3.0. Just change get_total_stock to get_stock_quantity

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'custom_get_availability', 1, 2);

function custom_get_availability( $availability, $_product ) {
  global $product;
  $stock = $product->get_stock_quantity();

  if ( $_product->is_in_stock() ) $availability['availability'] = __($stock . '', 'woocommerce');
  if ( !$_product->is_in_stock() ) $availability['availability'] = __('brak', 'woocommerce');

  return $availability;
}
```